# PyCharm не реагирует на команды

Tags: python, pycharm, pip

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке установить какую-либо библиотеку в pycharm, тот никак не реагирует на это
(Я обновлял pip и пытался установить через консоль виндовс, всё безуспешно)

Comment: Видите в правом нижнем углу версия питона... это текущий питон для проекта. Вот на него кликайте и там Interpreter Settings и там вам будет менеджер пакетов. Ну и с обычной внешней консолью проблем тоже не будет.

Comment: Не силен в PyCharm от слова совсем, но я бы смотрел в сторону виртуального пространства. Уверен, что PyCharm'у под силу иметь его и все зависимости для проекта в одном месте. И вам советую создавать отдельное виртуальное пространство для каждого проекта, если PyCharm это не делает автоматом. Утилита [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#module-venv) из коробки.

Comment: @Dmitry PyCharm все это умеет. Просто у него консоль работает по своим правилам. Никогда не пробовал вызывать в ней pip install, но вот потоки вывода субпроцессов теряет аж бегом.

Answer (score 1):

Заходите в: `File > Settings > Project: your_project_name > Project Interpreter > Нажимаешь на плюсик в верхнем углу списка установленных модулей > Вводишь название > Install Package` и все [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!