# В чем разница между venv и virtualenv? В чем разница между pip install и вкладкой PythonPackages в PyCharm? В чем разница между pip и poetry?

Tags: python, pycharm, pip, virtualenv, venv

В чем разница между venv, virtualenv и им подобными?
Насколько я знаю, venv - предустановленная в питон утилита, в то время как virtualenv - сторонняя библиотека. Что из этого использует PyCharm, когда создается дефолтный интерпретатор? (предположил, что venv, так как он идет в пачке с питоном, но название в окне выбора смутило)[image: virtualenv]

И сюда же следующий вопрос. В чем разница между добавлением библиотеки через pip install в терминале проекта, [image: pip install]

добавлением библиотеки через "+" в окне настройки интерпретатора
[image: окно интерпретатора]

и вкладкой Python Packages внизу окна, рядом с терминалом?
[image: Python Packages]

Также интересует объективное сравнение pip и poetry (и реально ли их сравнивать), так как ничего кроме pip не юзал, а хотелось бы. Пока видится разница лишь в том, что poetry собирает красиво файл зависимостей и бодро его обновляет, в то время как pip собирает файл кашу, который потом фиг грамотно обновишь (простите дилетанта).

Облазил англоязычные форумы (по теме venv), но удовлетворения не испытал. По возможности хотел бы выслушать грамотное объяснение шарящих людей, ибо после попыток объять необъятное за сутки, в голове какой-то сумбур.
Также хотел добавить, что уже видел эту [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1335678/В-чем-разница-между-venv-и-virtualenv](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1335678/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-venv-%D0%B8-virtualenv) тему на стаке (и ей предшествующий оригинал), но мне не хватило ясности касательно PyCharm'а.

Буду благодарен за уделенное время, если кто-то отважится разжевать эту тему понятным языком, ака для нубов со стажем.

Comment: Вкладка добавит пакет в питон для проекта, а через консоль может в системный, а может вообще [не будет работать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1369337/pycharm-не-реагирует-на-команды). В остальном же...у каждого инструмента свои недостатки и их выбор это уже сродни религии.

Comment: При работе через консоль с venv, предварительно его надо активировать. На windows это venv\scripts\activate. На linux это source venv/bin/activate. И только тогда через pip в venv можно будет что либо ставить. Либо запускать от интерпретатора в venv. В общем и целом вопрос конечно очень обширный, но мне самому было бы интересно узнать про отличия pip и poetry :)

Comment: Как таковой разницы между pip install и вкладкой PythonPackages нет. Просто pycharm может установить в предустановленное venv, если оно используется. pip install без активации виртуального окружения установит пакеты к системному интерпретатору. С активацией установит в venv folder.

Comment: В питоне в этом плане разброд и шатание. "Нужна изоляция" - virtualenv, "менеджер пакетов" -pip. "Отдельно 2 тулзы фу, пусть будет одна" - сделали pipenv. "У pip мало фич" - добавим до кучи pip-tools. "не такой резолв зависимостей и вообще душа не лежит" - родился poetry. "что за 100500 инструментов пусть будет один" - привет DepHell(уже мертв что ли?). "А что еще есть, а то мало выбора..." - pep-582, а именно  pythonloc  или из серьезного - pdm. А еще есть conda, pyenv, pipx...

Comment: @Exord недостаток pip в его работе с зависимостями. Он просто ставит зависимости текущего пакета, даже если стоит более новая зависимость, то есть вызывая даунгрейд зависимости. Также нельзя удалить пакет и его мусорные зависимости. Потому сразу нужно смотреть в сторону poetry или pdm, ведь они нормально разруливают такие случаи (хотя я poetry не пробовал, я использую pdm из-за его поддержки 2х вариантов изоляции) и работают с pypropject.toml. pip тоже уже умеет в pypropject.toml, но непонятно что он умеет то.